# Pass string variable in R script to use it in SQL statement

Tags: sql, r, variables

I tried use a string variable in R script to use through SQL statement for example:

```
x="PASS"

SQL<- paste("select ID, NAME, STATUS from STUDENT where STATUS =(",x,")",sep="")
Q1 <- dbGetQuery(con, SQL)
```

The ERROR says:

> Error in mysqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :
>   RS-DBI driver: (could not run statement: Unknown column 'PASS' in 'where clause')

That means STATUS =(",x,")" = PASS and it must 'PASS' with add quote ''

I tried to put the `''` but no success as the following.

```
SQL <- paste("select ID, NAME, STATUS from STUDENT where STATUS ='(",x,")' ",sep="")
Q1 <- dbGetQuery(con, SQL)
```

I tested it with number and it is work well but when I use string it is not working, because the value must be in quotes `' '`.

Answer (score 8):

Use `sprintf` instead:

```
x <- "PASS"
sprintf("select ID, NAME, STATUS from STUDENT where STATUS = '%s'", x)

## [1] "select ID, NAME, STATUS from STUDENT where STATUS = 'PASS'"
```

Comment: Thanks dickoa

I tried with sprintf and it is not work, in my case I use other variables type which contain integer.

The update of my case is:

x="PASS"
Y=1100
SQL<- paste("select ID, C_ID, NAME, STATUS from STUDENT where  C_ID=(",Y,")", and STATUS =(",x,")",sep="")

the previous case can deal Y but can not work with x


Please could help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
library(gsubfn)
x <- "PASS"

fn$dbGetQuery(con, "select ID, NAME, STATUS from STUDENT where STATUS = '$x' ")
```

This also works:

```
s <- fn$identity("select ID, NAME, STATUS from STUDENT where STATUS = '$x' ")
dbGetQuery(con, s)
```

Comment: Thanks G. Grothendieck, I tried it and it is work well with diffrent type of Variable.. and I would also to thanks all who reply..

Answer (score 2):

EDIT for windows

Try

```
x = "PASS"

SQL<- paste0("select ID, NAME, STATUS from STUDENT where STATUS = ", shQuote(x, 'sh'))
Q1 <- dbGetQuery(con, SQL)
```

More generally `shQuote` is useful for constructed things like:

```
paste0("SELECT * FROM urtable where urvar IN(", paste0(shQuote(LETTERS, 'sh'), collapse = ','), ")")
[1] "SELECT * FROM urtable where urvar IN('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z')"

 #
```

If you have simple character strings. For more complicated character strings other approaches maybe necessary. For example in PoSTgreSQL you can use `Dollar-Quoted String Constants` to escape characters.

You dont mention what variant of SQL you are using or associated R package. Some R packages may have helper functions like `postgresqlEscapeStrings` in `RPostgreSQL` or `dbEscapeStrings` in `RMySQL`.

Comment: You can keep the brackets or remove them.

Comment: This seems like a misuse of `shQuote`, which is meant for quoting strings for the _OS shell_. There's no guarantee that the same quotes are what a database would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Use glue_sql() from glue package.

x = "PASS"

glue_sql("select ID, NAME, STATUS from STUDENT where STATUS = {x}", .con = con)

see more examples here:
https://glue.tidyverse.org/#glue_sql-makes-constructing-sql-statements-safe-and-easy