# Replace Expression Parameter With Query in R

Tags: mysql, regex, r, expression

I have an expression max(51). I want to replace the parameter in the expression i.e. 51 with the values in the database with respect to this ID. So my replaced expression will be as below:

```
max(dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT VALUE FROM STUD WHERE ID=51"))
```

where con is MySQL connection object.
I have tried the following to extract the parameter from expression

```
PARAMETER <- gsub(".*\\((.*)\\)$", "\\1", "MAX(51)");
```

Now My final expression will become something like this:

```
max(dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT VALUE FROM STUD WHERE ID=PARAMETER"));
```

So how this replacement can be done in R? This is just a single operand  expression. Can it be possible for more complex expressions like

```
max(51)+min(52)-53
```

Thanks..

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: Do you already have an SQL query that you need to search and replace, or do you construct the query inside R?

Comment: I have the SQL query ready.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435086/how-to-pass-string-variable-in-r-script-to-use-it-through-sql-statement/17436174#17436174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this in the following way:

```
operand <- "max(51)";
PARAMETER <- gsub(".*\\((.*)\\)$", "\\1", operand);
QUERY=gsub("PARAMETER",PARAMETER,"SELECT VALUE FROM STUD WHERE ID='PARAMETER'");
Final_SubExpression <- gsub(PARAMETER,"dbGetQuery(con,QUERY)",operand);
Result <- eval(parse(text=Final_SubExpression));
Result;
```

OR

```
operand <- "max(51)";
PARAMETER <- gsub(".*\\((.*)\\)$", "\\1", operand);
QUERY=sprintf("SELECT VALUE FROM STUD WHERE ID = '%s'", PARAMETER);
Final_SubExpression <- gsub(PARAMETER,"dbGetQuery(con,QUERY)",operand);
Result <- eval(parse(text=Final_SubExpression));
Result;
```