# Generating Multiple tables via for loop or apply function in sql query

Tags: sql, r, for-loop, apply

I am basically running a query to get IDs for a specific year given a criteria . 
For example

```
table.2001=dbGetquery(conn,"Select ID from base table where x > 3 and year = 2001")
```

Now here i want to iterate over the year, (2001 to 2015) and  i get output table.2001, table.2002, table.2003 and so on for each year.

Comment: what is your problem? what you want to know from SO?

Comment: Use [SQL IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) for selected years, then use [R function split](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/split.html) to split the dataframe into list of dataframes based on "year" column. Or read about how to pass a [string into SQL statement as a variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17435086/680068)

Comment: Do you literally want to create tables for every year or just store resultset in some variable?

Comment: @zx875 - Thanks for the reply - but here i can have one ID say A coming multiple times in the same year . I want distinct ID as long as it satisfies the X>3 once in that year . and that  same ID  , can occur in next year again . so if i do distinct with IN , i guess it'll count that ID only once in the my sheet. I am looking at data sets . table.2001 = IDs : a , b ,c ,f     , table.2002 = IDs a , e , b     table.2003 = b , f , d etc and so on

Comment: @Maverick - thanks for the reply. yes i want to create results sets for each year separately through one for loop or apply function with sql query in R with dbgetQuery

Comment: I would suggest write a  for loop which starts with initial year and goes till final year. Auto increment every time until it reaches final year and store or process resultsets in loop.

Comment: Then use `mytable=dbGetquery(conn,"select year, ID from mytable where x > 3 and year between 2001 and 2003"` then use aggregate on "year" and "id" columns.

Comment: @Maverick - m struggling in saving results under different variables as per year in the for loop

Comment: No need for loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i in (2001:2003)) {
  assign(paste0("df",i),dbGetquery(conn,paste0("Select ID from base table where x > 3 and year = ",i)))
}
```

Comment: @r.user.05.apr - Super sir ! it worked , this is what i was looking for !