# why the syntax of sqldf is wrong

Tags: r, syntax, sqldf

I tried to select specific data from the data frame in a batch manner of R language(3.6) but failed.

When I use

```
sqldf("select * from Interact where miRNA = 'hsa-miR-510-5p' and
       Seqname ='chr3:195780289-195787118-' ")
```

it turned out ok.

While I tried

```
sqldf("select * from Interact where miRNA = Interpairs[1,1] and 
       Seqname =Interpairs[1,2]"),
```

or

```
sqldf('select * from Interact where miRNA = Interpairs$microRNA[1] and 
      Seqname = Interpairs$circRNA[1]')
```

it turned out wrong.

> Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "[1]": syntax error

I wonder whether anyone can help figure this out?

Comment: Its because your `Interpairs` is your R variable. Use `paste` or `sprintf` to pass those variables in SQL statment. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435086/pass-string-variable-in-r-script-to-use-it-in-sql-statement

Comment: `sqldf` magically bridges the gap in the presence/name of frames (as pseudo-tables), but does not bridge the gap for other variables. You might also consider `glue::glue_sql`.

Comment: I don't recommend using glue or other additional packages for that.  sqldf already contains facilities for this imported from the gsubfn package and exported back out so that you don't need to explicitly load it.. See my answer for the preferred approach.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I puzzeled it out with the method recommended by MKa and Grothendieck. Here is the code: ```fn$sqldf("select * from Interact where  miRNA= '`Interplym$microRNA[1]`' and Seqname = '`Interplym$circRNA[1]`' ")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string passed to `sqldf` must be SQL.  What you can do is insert the relevant content by prefacing `sqldf` with `fn$` as shown and then code within backquotes will be executed by R and its output substituted into the sql string at that point prior to passing the string to `sqldf`.

```
library(sqldf)
DF <- data.frame(a = 'x', b = 'y', stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # test data

fn$sqldf("select * from DF where a = '`DF$a[1]`' and b = '`DF$b[1]`' ")
##   a b
## 1 x y

fn$sqldf("select * from DF where a = '`DF[1,1]`' and b = '`DF[1,2]`' ")
##   a b
## 1 x y
```

Also `$variable` will substitute the variable's contents provided the variable name does not contain certain special characters:

```
a <- DF$a[1]
b <- DF$b[1]
fn$sqldf("select * from DF where a = '$a' and b = '$b' ")
##   a b
## 1 x y
```

If you want to see the string actually passed to `sqldf` then add the `verbose = TRUE` argument to any of the above `sqldf` calls.

### More info

There are several examples of this on the sqldf github home page: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf

Also info on `fn$` can be found via `?fn` .  Note that this is a general facility that works with just about any function and not just `sqldf`.  For example,

```
w <- "world"
fn$cat("Hello, $w\n")
## Hello, world
```

Comment: Thanks, Grothendieck. But I am still confused about the different result:

Comment: ```R  fn$sqldf("select * from Interact where  miRNA= '`Interpairs$microRNA[1]`' and Seqname = '`Interpairs$circRNA[1]`' ") ```    \n > [1] miRNA       Free Energy Seqname    
<0 row> (or 0-length of row.names) \n  ```R  fn$sqldf("select * from Interact where  miRNA= 'hsa-miR-510-5p' and Seqname = 'chr3:195780289-195787118-' ")```            miRNA Free Energy                   Seqname
1 hsa-miR-510-5p      -21.73 chr3:195780289-195787118-
2 hsa-miR-510-5p      -15.08 chr3:195780289-195787118-

Comment: Is it possible that the ranked  order will ascribe the variation?

Comment: Regarding the results reported in your comment, it is up to you to provide reproducible input when you report errors or unexpected results if you want help so that we can reproduce it..    Did you check that the string is what you thought it was as per the instructions in the answer?   Are you sure that your values are character and not factor?  other?